# How to generate numbers of 2D gaussian sources in an array?

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I want to generate a number of Gaussian sources in a fits array. My code is below.

```py
from astropy.io import fits
from numpy import *
xx=yy=1024
xc=xx/2.;yc=yy/2.
A=10.0
gau=zeros([xx,yy])
for i in range(xx):
  for j in range(yy):
      gau[i,j]=  A*exp(-((i-xc)/50.)**2 - ((j-yc)/50.)**2)
fits.writeto('gaussian_model.fits',gau,overwrite=True)
```

I iterated this over `n` numbers and added all Gaussians in the fits file. This is very slow to iterate over `(xx,yy)` for `n` numbers. Is there any other efficient way I should try to speed up the iterations over `(xx,yy)` for `n` sources?

Answer (score 3):

In order to implement a 2d gaussian efficiently in numpy, you should notice that a 2d gaussian is separable and can be implemented by multiplying two 1d gaussians, reducing the size of the arguments passed to `np.exp` (which is expensive) from `M * N` to `M + N`:

```
xx = 1024
yy = 1024

xc = xx / 2.
yc = yy / 2.
A = 10.0
x = np.arange(xx, dtype=np.float64)[:, None]
y = np.arange(yy, dtype=np.float64)[None, :]

x -= xc
y -= yc
x /= 50.
y /= 50.
x **= 2
y **= 2
x *= -1.
y *= -1.
x_exp = np.exp(x, out=x)
y_exp = np.exp(y, out=y)
A * x_exp * y_exp
```

Timings:

```
def op(xx=1024, yy=1024):
    xc=xx/2.;yc=yy/2.
    A=10.0
    gau=np.zeros([xx,yy])
    for i in range(xx):
        for j in range(yy):
            gau[i,j]=  A*np.exp(-((i-xc)/50.)**2 - ((j-yc)/50.)**2)
    return gau

def jared(xx=1024, yy=1024):

    xc = xx/2.
    yc = yy/2.

    A = 10.0

    XX, YY = np.meshgrid(np.arange(xx), np.arange(yy))
    return A*np.exp(-((XX-xc)/50.)**2 - ((YY-yc)/50.)**2)


def nin17(xx=1024, yy=1024):
    # Code from above


assert np.allclose(op(), jared())
assert np.allclose(op(), nin17())

%timeit op()
%timeit jared()
%timeit nin17()
```

Results:

```
608 ms ± 5.71 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
8.64 ms ± 518 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
905 µs ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought about splitting the exponential. I tested the speed of my code using broadcasting and it's faster but not as fast as your split method.

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up your code using vectorization (i.e. using numpy with the entire arrays rather than looping, essentially pushing the loop to the compiled C code, which is faster). This can be done using [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to make the combined arrays of `xx` and `yy` (essentially creates an array of the `xx` and `yy` combinations) or use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) by adding new axes. For both methods, you will have to create vectors of the `xx` and `yy` values, which I did by using [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) (numpy's method for creating a list with a given spacing, with the default being 1).

```py
import numpy as np

xx = 1024
yy = 1024

xc = xx/2.
yc = yy/2.

A = 10.0

YY, XX = np.meshgrid(np.arange(yy), np.arange(xx))
# or
# XX = np.arange(xx)[:, None]
# YY = np.arange(yy)[None, :]
gau = A*np.exp(-((XX-xc)/50.)**2 - ((YY-yc)/50.)**2)
```

You should read up on the [numpy basics here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html). If you're writing loops with numpy arrays then you're probably doing something wrong.

Also, it is bad practice to use `*` imports.

Comment: I think this should be ```XX, YY = np.meshgrid(np.arange(yy), np.arange(xx))``` for consistency with OP

Comment: @Nin17 Yes, I had thought about it but forgot to check. Thanks for catching that. I've updated my answer.